# Yet another complex SQL 2000 query issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have two tables that I want to use in my query, `tblEmployee` and `tblEmpPerformance`

The requirement is:

Using `tblEmployee.EmpID, tblEmployee.ManagerID`, go thru `tblEmpPerformance` and look at `tblEmpPerformance.SalaryRaise` and `tblEmpPerformance.CommissionRaise`, and update `tblEmployee` accordingly.

Only one of these two fields will have a non-zero value for every record in `tblEmpPerformance`

```
if tblEmployee.EmpID = tblEmpPerformance.EmpID then 
If tblEmpPerformance.Salary > 0 then
    update tblEmployee
    Set CompensationType = 'Salary'
    Where tblEmployee.EmpID = tblEmpPerformance.EmpID 
    AND tblEmployee.ManagerID = tblEmpPerformance.ManagerID   

    update tblEmployee
    Set SalaryRaise = tblEmpPerformance.SalaryRaise
    Where tblEmployee.EmpID = tblEmpPerformance.EmpID 
    AND tblEmployee.ManagerID = tblEmpPerformance.ManagerID 

If tblEmpPerformance.Commission > 0 then
    update tblEmployee
    Set CompensationType = 'Commission'
    Where tblEmployee.EmpID = tblEmpPerformance.EmpID 
    AND tblEmployee.ManagerID = tblEmpPerformance.ManagerID 

    update tblEmployee
    Set CommissionRaise = tblEmpPerformance.CommissionRaise
    Where tblEmployee.EmpID = tblEmpPerformance.EmpID 
    AND tblEmployee.ManagerID = tblEmpPerformance.ManagerID
```

If no matching `EmpID`'s found, then look in `tblContractorPerformance`

```
if tblEmployee.EmpID = tblContractorPerformance.EmpID then 
    If tblContractorPerformance.Salary > 0 then
    update tblEmployee
    Set CompensationType = 'Salary'
    Where tblEmployee.EmpID = tblContractorPerformance.EmpID 
    AND tblEmployee.ManagerID = tblContractorPerformance.ManagerID 
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....

Next tblEmployee.EmpID
```

Update:
DOH!!..
What would be the best way to write this SQL query. Stored Proc or cursor?
Any suggesstion on how to design the query would be a great help as well

Comment: But, what's the question, exactly? I'm thick today >_<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please avoid cursors.  Think set-based in dealing with your data.  So execute on your first set of data, where `tblEmpPerformance.Salary > 0`.  Do your updates, then do the second operation on the next set of data where `tblEmpPerformance.Commission > 0`.  Lastly, update all the data where the `tblContractorPerformance.Salary > 0`.

Put these operations in a stored procedure and I'm confident you'll see better performance than the equivalent using cursors.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU !!!!!!!!!! That was my suggestion, but got shot down by upper mgmt. The "Thank you" is to say thanks for validating my solution. :-)

Comment: lol.  I have anecdotal evidence - had a ton of stored procedures that were cursor-based. they took hours to run.  I rewrote them set-based, and they took about 30 seconds total.

Comment: For some reason, the longer it takes the query to process, the more the customer thinks "this is complex stuff that they are doing for us... they are worth the $250/hr fee". Anyway, got a buy in from upper mgmt. Everybody happy !!   :-)

Comment: ya, the $250/hr consultants wrote the CURSOR code, then I came in as the $25/hr staff programmer had to rewrite the code to actually run correctly.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, you can encapsulate this into a single query:

```
Update tblEmployee
Set CompensationType = Case
                        When EP.Commission > 0 Then 'Commission'
                        When EP.Salary > 0 Then 'Salary'
                        When CP.Salary > 0 Then 'Salary'
                        Else E.CompensationType -- leave value as is
                        End
    , CommissionRaise = Case
                        When EP.Commission > 0 Then EP.CommissionRaise
                        Else E.CommissionRaise -- leave value as is
                        End
    , SalaryRaise = Case
                        When EP.Commission > 0 Then E.SalaryRaise
                        When EP.Salary > 0 Then EP.SalaryRaise
                        When CP.Salary > 0 Then CP.SalaryRaise
                        Else E.SalaryRaise -- leave value as is
                        End
From tblEmployee As E
    Left Join tblEmployeePerformance As EP
        On EP.EmpID = E.EmpID
            And EP.ManagerId = E.ManagerId
    Left Join tblContractorPerformance As CP
        On CP.EmpID = E.EmpID
            And CP.ManagerId = E.ManagerId
```